# El Action del commanButton de jsf no hace nada

Tags: eclipse, jsf, hibernate

Tengo una aplicación web y a la hora de accionar el botón guardar no hace nada... Aquí esta el código:

```
<!-- Aqui se crean los elementos que seran utilizados por el usuario -->
<div class="container" id="formu">
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 200px;">
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán; font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Id Incidencia:          " for="incidencia"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.idIncidencia}" id="incidencia"></p:inputText>
            <br /> <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Nombres:          " for="nombre"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.nom_Usuario}" id="nombre"></p:inputText>
            <br /> <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Apellidos:        " for="apellido"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.apell_Usuario}" id="apellido"></p:inputText>
            <br /> <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Empresa:          " for="empresa"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.empresa_Usuario}" id="empresa"></p:inputText>
            <br /> <br />
        </div>

        <div style="position: relative; left: 430px; bottom: 20px;">

            <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Ciudad:           " for="ciudad"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.ciudad_Usuario}" id="ciudad"></p:inputText>
            <br /> <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Fecha Inicio:      " for="fechaInicio" />
            <br />
            <p:calendar value="#{mBean.fecha_Inicio}" id="fechaInicio" />
            <br /> <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Fecha Terminacion: " for="fechaFin" />
            <br />
            <p:calendar value="#{mBean.fecha_Fin}" id="fechaFin"
                effect="fold" />
            <br /> <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Correo - E-mail:   " for="correo"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.correo_Usuario}" id="correo"></p:inputText>
        </div>

        <div style="position: relative; left: 800px; bottom: 345px;">

            <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Telefono:          " for="telefono"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.tel_Usuario}" id="telefono"></p:inputText>
            <br /> <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Tipo Incidencia:   " for="tipo"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.categoriaIncidencia}" id="tipo"></p:inputText>
            <br /> <br />
            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Nivel Riesgo Incidencia:   " for="riesgo"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.subCategorias}" id="riesgo"></p:inputText>
            <br /> <br />

            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Pais:           " for="pais"></p:outputLabel>
            <br />
            <p:inputText value="#{mBean.pais_Usuario}" id="pais"></p:inputText>

        </div>

        <br />
        <div style="text-align: center; position: relative; bottom: 350px;">

            <p:outputLabel
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                value="Descricion: " for="descripcion"></p:outputLabel>

            <br />
            <p:inputTextarea value="#{mBean.observacion}"
                style="font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;"
                id="descripcion" rows="6" cols="70" label="descripcion" />
            <br /> <br />
        </div>

        <div style="text-align: center; position: relative; bottom: 350px;">

            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{}"
                style="width:720px; font-family: Cormorán;font-size:18px;font-weight: normal;
                background-color:#C5FF9B;"
                value="Guardar" icon="ui-icon-check" type="button" >
                <f:ajax execute="myForm" render="formu" />
                </p:commandButton>

        </div>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

**Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MBean implements Serializable{

    private int idIncidencia;
    private String Nom_Usuario;
    private String Apell_Usuario;
    private String Tel_Usuario;
    private String Correo_Usuario;
    private String Fecha_Inicio;
    private String Fecha_Fin;
    private String observacion;
    private String Empresa_Usuario;
    private String CategoriaIncidencia;
    private String SubCategorias;
    private String Pais_Usuario;
    private String Ciudad_Usuario;

    public MBean() {
    }

    public void agregarInc() {
        Incidencia incidencia = new Incidencia(getIdIncidencia(), 
                getNom_Usuario(),
                getApell_Usuario(), 
                getFecha_Inicio(), 
                getFecha_Fin(),
                getCategoriaIncidencia(),
                getSubCategorias(),
                getCorreo_Usuario(),
                getTel_Usuario(),
                getCiudad_Usuario(),
                getPais_Usuario(),
                getObservacion(),
                getEmpresa_Usuario());
        IncidenciaDao incDao = new IncidenciaDao();
        incDao.Registrar(incidencia);
    }

    public int getIdIncidencia() {
        return idIncidencia;
    }

    public void setIdIncidencia(int idIncidencia) {
        this.idIncidencia = idIncidencia;
    }

    public String getNom_Usuario() {
        return Nom_Usuario;
    }

    public void setNom_Usuario(String nom_Usuario) {
        Nom_Usuario = nom_Usuario;
    }

    public String getApell_Usuario() {
        return Apell_Usuario;
    }

    public void setApell_Usuario(String apell_Usuario) {
        Apell_Usuario = apell_Usuario;
    }

    public String getTel_Usuario() {
        return Tel_Usuario;
    }

    public void setTel_Usuario(String tel_Usuario) {
        Tel_Usuario = tel_Usuario;
    }

    public String getCorreo_Usuario() {
        return Correo_Usuario;
    }

    public void setCorreo_Usuario(String correo_Usuario) {
        Correo_Usuario = correo_Usuario;
    }

    public String getFecha_Inicio() {
        return Fecha_Inicio;
    }

    public void setFecha_Inicio(String fecha_Inicio) {
        Fecha_Inicio = fecha_Inicio;
    }

    public String getFecha_Fin() {
        return Fecha_Fin;
    }

    public void setFecha_Fin(String fecha_Fin) {
        Fecha_Fin = fecha_Fin;
    }

    public String getObservacion() {
        return observacion;
    }

    public void setObservacion(String observacion) {
        this.observacion = observacion;
    }

    public String getEmpresa_Usuario() {
        return Empresa_Usuario;
    }

    public void setEmpresa_Usuario(String empresa_Usuario) {
        Empresa_Usuario = empresa_Usuario;
    }

    public String getCategoriaIncidencia() {
        return CategoriaIncidencia;
    }

    public void setCategoriaIncidencia(String categoriaIncidencia) {
        CategoriaIncidencia = categoriaIncidencia;
    }

    public String getSubCategorias() {
        return SubCategorias;
    }

    public void setSubCategorias(String subCategorias) {
        SubCategorias = subCategorias;
    }

    public String getPais_Usuario() {
        return Pais_Usuario;
    }

    public void setPais_Usuario(String pais_Usuario) {
        Pais_Usuario = pais_Usuario;
    }

    public String getCiudad_Usuario() {
        return Ciudad_Usuario;
    }

    public void setCiudad_Usuario(String ciudad_Usuario) {
        Ciudad_Usuario = ciudad_Usuario;
    }

}
```

**DAO**

```
public class IncidenciaDao {
    public void Registrar(Incidencia inc) {
        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(inc);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Clase**

```
public class Incidencia {
    private int idIncidencia ;
    private String Nom_Usuario;
    private String Apell_Usuario; 
    private String  Tel_Usuario ;
    private String Correo_Usuario;
    private String Fecha_Inicio ;
    private String Fecha_Fin ;
    private String observacion; 
    private String Empresa_Usuario;
    private String CategoriaIncidencia; 
    private String SubCategorias ;
    private String  Pais_Usuario ;
    private String Ciudad_Usuario;

    public Incidencia(){
    }

    public Incidencia(int idIncidencia, String nom_Usuario, String apell_Usuario, String tel_Usuario,
            String correo_Usuario, String fecha_Inicio, String fecha_Fin, String observacion, String empresa_Usuario,
            String categoriaIncidencia, String subCategorias, String pais_Usuario, String ciudad_Usuario) {
        this.idIncidencia = idIncidencia;
        this.Nom_Usuario = nom_Usuario;
        this.Apell_Usuario = apell_Usuario;
        this.Tel_Usuario = tel_Usuario;
        this.Correo_Usuario = correo_Usuario;
        this.Fecha_Inicio = fecha_Inicio;
        this.Fecha_Fin = fecha_Fin;
        this.observacion = observacion;
        this.Empresa_Usuario = empresa_Usuario;
        this.CategoriaIncidencia = categoriaIncidencia;
        this.SubCategorias = subCategorias;
        this.Pais_Usuario = pais_Usuario;
        this.Ciudad_Usuario = ciudad_Usuario;
    }

    public int getIdIncidencia() {
        return idIncidencia;
    }
    public void setIdIncidencia(int idIncidencia) {
        this.idIncidencia = idIncidencia;
    }
    public String getNom_Usuario() {
        return Nom_Usuario;
    }
    public void setNom_Usuario(String nom_Usuario) {
        Nom_Usuario = nom_Usuario;
    }
    public String getApell_Usuario() {
        return Apell_Usuario;
    }
    public void setApell_Usuario(String apell_Usuario) {
        Apell_Usuario = apell_Usuario;
    }
    public String getTel_Usuario() {
        return Tel_Usuario;
    }
    public void setTel_Usuario(String tel_Usuario) {
        Tel_Usuario = tel_Usuario;
    }
    public String getCorreo_Usuario() {
        return Correo_Usuario;
    }
    public void setCorreo_Usuario(String correo_Usuario) {
        Correo_Usuario = correo_Usuario;
    }
    public String getFecha_Inicio() {
        return Fecha_Inicio;
    }
    public void setFecha_Inicio(String fecha_Inicio) {
        Fecha_Inicio = fecha_Inicio;
    }
    public String getFecha_Fin() {
        return Fecha_Fin;
    }
    public void setFecha_Fin(String fecha_Fin) {
        Fecha_Fin = fecha_Fin;
    }
    public String getObservacion() {
        return observacion;
    }
    public void setObservacion(String observacion) {
        this.observacion = observacion;
    }
    public String getEmpresa_Usuario() {
        return Empresa_Usuario;
    }
    public void setEmpresa_Usuario(String empresa_Usuario) {
        Empresa_Usuario = empresa_Usuario;
    }
    public String getCategoriaIncidencia() {
        return CategoriaIncidencia;
    }
    public void setCategoriaIncidencia(String categoriaIncidencia) {
        CategoriaIncidencia = categoriaIncidencia;
    }
    public String getSubCategorias() {
        return SubCategorias;
    }
    public void setSubCategorias(String subCategorias) {
        SubCategorias = subCategorias;
    }
    public String getPais_Usuario() {
        return Pais_Usuario;
    }
    public void setPais_Usuario(String pais_Usuario) {
        Pais_Usuario = pais_Usuario;
    }
    public String getCiudad_Usuario() {
        return Ciudad_Usuario;
    }
    public void setCiudad_Usuario(String ciudad_Usuario) {
        Ciudad_Usuario = ciudad_Usuario;
    }
}
```

**Util**

```
public class HibernateUtil {
     private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory=buildSessionFactory();

       public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){
            try {
                return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hola Celis, te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta para asegurar que tenga el formato correcto. Selecciona cada formato de código y oprime `Control` + `K`.

Answer (score 0):

Cual sería la acción que debería ejecutar?

Te comento que tu commandButton no tiene asignado ningún action listener: `actionListener="#{}"`

Es decir, no hay ningún  [method expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html) en el EL y por ende ninguna invocación a tu controller.

Imagino que lo que quieres hacer es invocar al metodo `agregarInc()` a través de `actionListener="#{mBean.agregarInc}"`